# Change URL in browser (fake URL) for cinematography

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, url

In a project I am currently in charge of, we have to code fake Web pages for a film scenario. (The comedian is using a computer and navigating (locally) on the browser (Chrome).

As I cannot use PHP for local changes, neither simply change the URL location with Javascript for security reasons, how can I modify the URL content ?

**Example** :

file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Project/SEARCH/4.html

to

http://www.some-web-site-here.com/fake/url/page.html

Thank you for your responses !

Comment: First things first: please, [**read the FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), this question is really Off-Topic. Anyway, can't you simply copy-paste the url on the url-bar without pressing "Enter"? Another option is that you could edit your `/etc/hosts` file to redirect the url to localhost or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an onpopstate handler to control the url in the address bar.

See here for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate

Comment: Thanks, I read the documentation about pushState() and replaceState() although, this cannot help me archive what I need as 
"The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise, pushState() will throw an exception. This parameter is optional; if it isn't specified, it's set to the document's current URL." I think my problem is more complex as I want to perform something that would go against the browser security, similarly as spoofing a URL... I am still thinking about a solution.